# Qt - Building a project

Tags: c++, qt, build, project

I'm trying to build a Qt project by typing `make` on a `Microsoft Windows 7` platform, but get the following:

`mingw32-make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Why is that? How can I build the project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your include path contains:

```
mingw32-make
```

Check your [environment variables](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html) .

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *Qt Command Prompt* from the Qt SDK.

It will automatically set the correct environment variables for you.